# SQL: How can I order null and empty entries to the front in an orderby?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have the following entries in my database:

ID Name
1  [null]
2  [empty string]
3  Alpha
4  Bravo
5  Charlie

..then how can I order the rows with names to the front when using ORDER BY?

If I use ORDER BY Name, I get the list above, but I actually want:

3 Alpha
4 Bravo
5 Charlie
1 [null]
2 ''

Comment: Does a null value have to come before an empty string or are they the same?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
    WHEN Name IS NULL THEN 1 
    WHEN Name = ''    THEN 2 
    ELSE 3 
    END DESC, 
    Name ASC
```

Comment: DESC to get the names at the top?

Comment: Should be `order by descending` since he wants NULL and empty strings at the bottom

Comment: +1 very efficient ways...you know SO a gold mine to learn new things every moment. If you would give the answer. I would have used three union statements filtering the records, that meant went to database three times:)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Name IS NULL then 3 WHEN Name = '' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, Name
```

It will order with by the number in the case first and afterwords by the Name.

Answer (score 2):

```
ORDER BY 
CASE 
    WHEN Name IS NULL THEN 1 
    WHEN Name = '' THEN 2 
    ELSE 3
END DESC,
Name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN Name IS NULL THEN 1 WHEN Name IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 3 END) DESC
```