# SQL order by date AND by time

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time, sql-order-by

Having table with fields 'date' (YYYY-MM-dd) and 'time' (hh:mm am/pm), but time sometimes may be blank.
Is it possible to order items by date and by time with such structure?

Comment: Any reason you're using text fields for this?

Comment: You can use order by that field name, and use case condition if null or blank. [This-link-might-help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021526/sql-how-can-i-order-null-and-empty-entries-to-the-front-in-an-orderby)

Comment: "Any reason you're using text fields for this?" Long story... Really don't want to regenerate it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can just separate the column names with a comma to achieve this:

```
ORDER BY date, time
```

You'll need to appropriately handle 'blank' times (ie should they be placed before or after non-blanks in the result set):

```
ORDER BY date, time DESC
```

**UPDATE** Handle am and pm appropriately

In order to achieve this you can use the [SUBSTRING_INDEX function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
ORDER BY date, SUBSTRING_INDEX(time, " ", -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(time, " ", 1)
```

Comment: Are you sure that it will sort correctly '11:00 am' and '10:00 pm' ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SELECT * FROM customer_tbl ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC
```

this should help you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `ORDER BY Date, Time` and that will order by the available data in the fields.  The blank values will order together at the end of the results.