# Can I apply something like `NULLS LAST` but without sorting by that column values that are not null?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Imagine I have query

```
 SELECT  "somethings.* 
 FROM "somethings" 
 ORDER BY description DESC NULLS LAST, popularity DESC`
```

It will sort first on description, put all rows with `null` description at the end, and then apply popularity sort.

But what I want is just to put rows with null description last, not to sort results primary on description string, and then sort results on popularity.

Ideally I want to achieve it in one query.

Comment: This is a good one. I don't know how to do it, but I'll pay attention to the answers.

Comment: Some sample data would really help here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: How can I order null and empty entries to the front in an orderby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021526/sql-how-can-i-order-null-and-empty-entries-to-the-front-in-an-orderby)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `is null` in `order by` clause :

```
order by (case when description is null 
               then 1 else 0 end), description desc, popularity desc;
```

Answer (score 3):

slighly shorter solution

```
ORDER BY description IS NOT NULL, description, popularity DESC
```

This works because `True` > `False`